# Have modal always appear in view after scroll

Tags: html, css

I'm running into an issue where if a user scrolls down my site and then the modal pops up, it will always pop up at the top of the page, so it requires them to scroll all the way back up to interact.

Is there a way to get the modal to always pop up in view even if they scroll?

.modal creates the background shadow and then the modal-content is where the modal content appears.

Thank you in advance.

```css
.modal {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

.modal-content {
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    margin: 15% auto;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 70%;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.17), 0 7px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.17)
}
```

Comment: set `body { overflow-y: hidden }` when the modal is open

Answer (score 0):

Use [`position: fixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#fixed) on your `.modal` class. Using the `fixed` property will attach an element to a fixed position on the *screen*, not relative to its container.